# How to access elements faster?

Tags: c++

I'm working on statistical data for program runs. I want to log the virtual address being visited. Afterwards I was able to tell if an address had already been visited.

When I use vector to record all visited addresses.

```
has_access = std::count(access_addresses.begin(), prefetch_addresses.end(), block_number);
```

Then use the above function to determine whether the element has been visited before.
But because there are too many elements, the search takes a lot of time. A program that used to end in 30 minutes now takes 10 hours.

Using an array seems like a good idea. For example `array[access_address] = 1;` to record previously accessed elements.
But since addresses are 48 bits, this seems to imply an unacceptable storage overhead.

Is there any better way?

Comment: This sounds like a job for an unordered set or map. Just make sure the hash function of your 48bit address is blazing. If ordering is important, a regular set or map may be an alternative.

Comment: Make sure you are compiling your code with optimizations enabled.

Comment: *Using an array seems like a good idea* -- Unless the array is sorted and thus can do a binary search, storing millions of elements (I'm assuming it's that many) and doing a linear search is a bad idea.  It shouldn't even have been considered, to be honest with you.  Either sort the data and search it using binary search, or use what was suggested (std::unordered_set, etc.).  This really boils down to knowledge of data structures and the proper data structure to use, and isn't really a C++ issue.

Comment: If using an array, no search is required. Directly use the address as the index of the array.

Comment: @Gerrie if the addresses are things like `0x782456DE` Then your array could be millions of elements and enormous in memory.

Comment: Yes. I stated this in the question.